# Is there a way to detect what Windows Store apps are installed on a system with native C# calls?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the [Get-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx) and [Get-ProvisionedAppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852131.aspx) Powershell cmdlets for a C# application I'm building, but have no idea how to even get started.

I can't use the C# Powershell API because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640564/c-sharp-system-management-automation-powershell-class-leaking-memory-on-invoke), so I'd like a native C# solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Windows.Management.Deployement.PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) to find, remove, install, etc. packages from code rather than from PowerShell.

The [Enumerate app packages sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/package-manager-inventory-ee821079) demonstrates how to use this from C# and C++.

Comment: Great! Exactly the perfect solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I did find a way to get this information directly from WMI: There's a WMI class called Win32_InstalledStoreProgram that returns the desired information